# Incrementing a unicode character?

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to print some Hindi numbers (Unicode range: 0966 - 096F) in my Java code.
The printing is tied to an `index` that is being incremented by a `for loop`. Some sample code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println(/* I need the Hindi numbers from 0-9 printed here (value of i in each iteration but in Hindi));
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
System.out.println("\u0966" + i);
```

Needless to say, that is not working. My question is:
1. How do I increment a number that is represented in Unicode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println((char)(0x966+i));
}
```

Comment: The `""+` is not required.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println((char) ('\u0966' + i));
    }
```